# Persisted data with Django and Algolia search model indexing

Tags: python, django, algolia, django-1.11

This is a curious one for Django+Algolia. I'm using the Algolia specific Django package:

```
$ pip install algoliasearch-django
```

I have the following model schema:

```
import os
import datetime

from channels import Group

from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.utils.six import python_2_unicode_compatible
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.files.storage import FileSystemStorage
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
SITE_UPLOAD_LOC = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads/site'))
USER_UPLOAD_LOC = FileSystemStorage(location=os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'uploads/user'))

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Room(models.Model):
    """
    This model class sets up the room that people can chat within - much like a forum topic.
    """
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=250, default='')
    banner = models.ImageField(storage=USER_UPLOAD_LOC, null=True, blank=True)

    def last_activity(self):
        """
        For date and time values show how many seconds, minutes, or hours ago a message
        was sent (i.e., persised to the database) compared to current timestamp return representing string.
        """
        last_persisted_message = Messages.objects.filter(where=self.slug).order_by('-sent_at').first()
        if last_persisted_message is not None:
            # First we can store "last persisted message" time in ISO format (could be useful for sitemap.xml generation; SEO tasks etc)
            last_persisted_message_iso = last_persisted_message.sent_at.isoformat()
            # Use the natural time package form contrib.humanize to convert our datetime to a string.
            last_persisted_message = naturaltime(last_persisted_message.sent_at)
            return last_persisted_message
        else:
            return "No activity to report"
```

Which is indexed as:

```
from algoliasearch_django import AlgoliaIndex

class RoomIndex(AlgoliaIndex):
    fields = ('title', 'last_activity')

    settings = {
        'searchableAttributes': ['title'],
        'attributesForFaceting': ['title', 'last_activity'],
        'hitsPerPage': 15,
    }

    index_name = 'Room Index'
```

Essentially, to bring the 'last_activity' value to the front end it needs to pass through the index which is updated as far as I can tell with running:

```
$ python manage.py algolia_reindex
```

However, the last activity comes from the last time (converted to humanized django naturaltime, e.g. '3 days ago' etc etc) a Message was sent within a websocket connection - persisted to the database. All of this functionality works except that to update I need to run the algolia_reindex command.

Rather unsure as to how this could potentially be done a little more simultaneously...?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so this one was slightly more complex as I was using websockets. When a message is sent and persisted to the database we can also do the following within the relevant "consumer" method (really, consumers.py is the websocket equivalent of the views.py file so I should have known this!)

The following lines of code worked:

```
client = algoliasearch.Client(settings.ALGOLIA['APPLICATION_ID'], settings.ALGOLIA['API_KEY'])
index = client.init_index('Room Index')
res = index.partial_update_objects([{"last_activity": naturaltime(datetime.datetime.now()), "objectID": your_object_id]}])
```

The trick for anyone listening would be to designate the your_object_id from what value of the message is passed in from the client side to the consumer.

Don't forget to add:

```
import datetime
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime
```

At the top of the consumers.py file!

I also found the python specific incremental updates documentation from Algolia extremely useful:
    I https://www.algolia.com/doc/tutorials/indexing/synchronization/incremental-updates/

To render the updated time in "real time" - use which ever front-end tool floats your boat, I used jQuery but Vue.js or React.js would work equally well.

Comment: Hey thanks for the follow up! Don't hesitate to post your issue in https://github.com/algolia/algoliasearch-django/issues